# How to add a button to the view dynamically?

Tags: kotlin, javafx, tornadofx

I'm new to Kotlin and TorandoFX. Maybe I'm missing something very basic in TornadoFX. I want to create from a list (which shoulde be mutable) buttons in the view. If the user clicks on the add button the list should get a new item and this should result in a new button in the view.
Thank you for your help.

I was thinking it should look like this:

```
import tornadofx.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}

class MyApp: App(MainView::class)

class MainView: View("MainView") {
    val values = ArrayList<Int>(listOf(1,2,3)).asObservable()
    var count = 4

    override val root = vbox {
        values.forEach { x ->
            button(x.toString())
        }

        button("add") {
            action {
                values.add(count)
                println(values.toString())
                count++
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[this code result in this view, but if I click the button the view doesnt refresh.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIgXA.png)
This code result in this view, but if I click the button the view doesnt refresh. I think I'm missing something about binding.

Comment: I don't know TornadoFX but what makes you believe that an additional button is created just because you added a value to your observable list?

Comment: I thought, because I iterrate over the list in the view it would update them self.

Comment: But you're not iterating over the values in the button's event handler, as far as I can see (I don't know TornadoFX/kotlin either). The event handler needs to create an additional button and add it to the vbox.

Comment: Your code, which creates the buttons, is only executed once when the constructor is executed, but, as @James_D has already pointed out, it is not executed in your event handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured out, I was right with the binding part. I just had to use `bindChildren()` function and give the function an observableArray and a function to for the conversion of the elements of the array as a parameter.
Thank you for the help.

```
import javafx.collections.FXCollections
import tornadofx.*

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    launch<MyApp>(args)
}

class MyApp: App(MainView::class)

class MainView: View("MainView") {
    val values = FXCollections.observableArrayList<Int>(listOf(1,2,3))
    var count = 4

    override val root = vbox {
        vbox {
            bindChildren(values) { x ->
                button(x.toString())
            }
        }

        vbox() {
            button("add") {
                action {
                    values.add(count)
                    count++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using TornadoFX?  You don't HAVE to use it to use JavaFX with Kotlin.